# Adding a group of images to ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a `ListView` and a `List<Image>` (there are 3 images in the list). I'm trying to add all the images to the `ListView` and currently this is what I have:

```
foreach (Image image in ListOfImages)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
    pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    pictureBox.Width = 200;
    pictureBox.Height = 200;
    pictureBox.Image = image;
    pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

    listView1.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
}
```

And this is what it looks like in the end:

[image]

That image is the first one in my list. The other two aren't visible. Is there a reason why the others aren't showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found that the correct answer for what I want to do is to not use a `ListView` but to instead use a `FlowLayoutPanel`. The code above will work exactly the same way, except instead of `listView1` it should be `flowLayoutPanel1` (or whatever the name of the `FlowLayoutPanel` is)

Answer (score 1):

I think microsoft has a better solution to offer - ImageList.
Why can't you use the ImageList?

I can help you one that
First create an Imagelist control from Toolbox.
Set your istview's imagelist.
e.g. `listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;`

```
foreach (Image image in ListOfImages)
{
    imageList1.Images.Add(image);
}
```

Add list Items to your list control and mention the respective image index.

```
 listView1.Items.Add(key, text, imageindex);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, that'd be a great solution, but I'd like to figure it out with the `listView1.Controls` in case I want to use different controls in the future (eg a `WebBrowser` for instance